# Can the partial fraction method of integration be used with trig functions contained inside the function to be integrated?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, partial-fractions

Can the partial fractions method be used to integrate a problem like this? $$\int\frac{1}{\cos(x)\left(\sin^2(x)+4\right)}dx$$
Or, do the trig functions contained inside the denominator ruin it? 
If yes, would this be the setup: $$\frac{A}{\cos(x)}+\frac{Bx+C}{\sin^2(x)+4}$$

Comment: Is it possible to find such numbers $A$, $B$, and $C$ for which the attempted expansion is valid?

Comment: As I'm working it, I have not found, but I do not yet know that I am working it right. @MarkViola

Comment: @kolobokish huh??

Answer (score 3):

It is better to change a variable first:
$$\int\frac{dx}{\cos(x)\left(\sin^2(x)+4\right)}=\int\frac{\cos x \,dx}{\cos^2(x)\left(\sin^2(x)+4\right)}=\left[\begin{array}{c}t=\sin x \\ dt=\cos x\,dx\end{array}\right]=\int\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)\left(t^2+4\right)}$$
Now you can use partial fraction. 
You can also see that the denominators you'll get are not exactly what you'd expected.

Comment: so, in order to do that substitution you multiplied by $\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}$

Comment: @Burt yup, just to make the right numerator for the substitution.

Comment: Is the resulting partial fraction setup: $\frac{A}{1+t}+\frac{B}{1-t}+\frac{Ct+D}{t^2+4}$?